# Permission denied when setting up nginx on RHEL despite read-all access and file ownership

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, permissions

Yea I know there are many such question on here.  But I think mine is different.

Background: I'm setting up nginx.  I'm configuring nginx to use user "nginx", and error log says "/home/ec2-user/MIP/public/js/main.js" failed (13: Permission denied)

Problem:
I checked that it's readable by anyone and nginx is the owner:

```
-rwxrw-r-x 1 nginx nginx 20765 Jul  2 02:26 /home/ec2-user/MIP/public/js/main.js
```

But permission still denied.

```
sudo -u nginx cat /home/ec2-user/MIP/public/js/main.js
cat: /home/ec2-user/MIP/public/js/main.js: Permission denied
```

This itself is already sufficient for it to be accessible by nginx yes?  Or user nginx just won't be able to access anything under /home/ec2-user?

Comment: Most likely nginx can't read one of the intermediate directories, like /home/ec2-user.

Comment: yea, I've got it working finally after permanently putting my project folder from /home/ec2-user/ to /var/www.  Is this an appropriate place tho?

Comment: Perfectly cromulent.